# pitchipoy IKFK parameter not showing in dopesheet or fcurves

Tags: rigify

i am using blender 2.76 on win 8.1 x64.
if i create normal metarig, generate and select arm control and insert keyframe with RMB on IKFK parameter in property bar, i get keyframes start showing on 'newly created action in dopesheet or fcurves.
where as similar behaviour on pitchipoy meta rig , generate and attempt to keyframe IKFK parameter doesn't show keyframe / channel name in fcurve. it shows a keysframe in dopsheet main action  (top) but i can't move it, and no special channel is added, i can't see that in time time or fcurve.
any ideas would be appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ahh, i found solution. If anyone is in same situation. rig maintain ALL IK FK switches and stretch options at end of dopesheet (mostly hidden) you have to make sure, following

- mouse icon "showing selected object channels" is OFF
- ghost icon "include channels from bone hidden etc" is ON

now when i know this, i think its very reasonable to have them there separately managed. this behavious is slightly different than rigify but good enough. thanks pitchypoy for awesome rig.